# Setting an object property as an array value

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to build an object in which the properties of the object don't exist directly on the object, but rather are defined through a static variable and stored into a `$data` property, through the user of `__get` and `__set`. It's working out well, until I've gotten to objects. Because of the issue with recursive objects and not having access to create getters and setters on `stdClass`, I figured internally I can store the values of the object as an array and cast it on output. Unfortunately when someone does something like

```
$fleet->car->wheels = 4;
```

I immediately get

```
Creating default object from empty value
```

It seems to indicate that it tries to do the outer set (`car->wheels`) first, then the inner? Which doesn't make sense to me. To me, logically it'd first try to get the value of `car` from `$fleet`, then try to set `wheels`.

Am I thinking about this incorrectly or is this just not possible? I know the other solution is to create an object to hold the values, with getters/setters of it's own, but I'd like to have as little code as possible.

The minimum code to see this:

```
class Test
{
    public function __set($key, $value) {
        var_dump($key, $value);
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->car->wheels = 4;
```

Comment: This is an interesting question. Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you share your class codes

Answer (score 1):

This was a mistake in logic.

When you set `{object}->{key1}->{key2}`, you're getting `{object}->{key1}`, then setting the return of that. So the fact that I was trying to use a setter that wasn't firing was, of course, because a value in `{key1}` was being set, but not `key1` itself.

So adding

```
public function __get($key) {
    $test = new stdClass();
    return $test;
}
```

got rid of the error, because first a new `stdClass` for `car` is created, and then 4 is set to `wheels`.